# Как разделить видеофайл на сцены

Tags: python, opencv, видео

Есть видеофайл, представляющий собой нарезку из разных роликов. Необходимо разделить его на эти ролики. Мне приходит в голову один только вариант - разложить файл на отдельные кадры и сравнивать каждый последующий с предыдущим (как? По какому алгоритму?). Если разница будет больше какого то определенного экспериментальным путем значения, то значит старая сцена кончилась и началась новая.
Возможно, задачу можно немного упростить, если предположить, что алгоритм сжатия видео будет ставить ключевые кадры, в том числе, и на границах сцен, там ведь картинка будет меняться резко и сильно. Тогда можно сравнивать между собой не все кадры, а только в окрестностях ключевых кадров. Но непонятно пока, как достать эти самые ключевые кадры. Решать задачу предполагаю с помощью python и openCV.
Прошу идей.

Comment: Укажите примеры данных и их объём

Comment: Ролики с Ютуба: всяческие нарезки юмористических подборок, про дтп, курьёзные случаи и т.д. Длительность ориентировочно 30 минут, формат mp4.

Comment: Этот алгоритм уже сто раз написан. Смотрите в потроха ffmpeg. По сути пороговое значение вам даст намёк, что пора делать так называемый "опорный кадр". Вот это и будет оно. Там же есть поддержка нарезки.